# Change custom post type slug from Settings > Permalinks page

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_types' );
function register_my_types() {
    register_post_type( 'movies',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Movies' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Movie' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'films'
            ),
        )
    );
}
```

I can use the following to change the slug from my plugin settings page (on save to get 'filme' from a field):

```
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'movies_register_post_type_args', 10, 2 );
function movies_register_post_type_args( $args, $post_type ) {

    if ( 'movies' === $post_type ) {
        $args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'filme';
    }

    return $args;
}
```

But, I want to be able to modify the "films" slug from Settings > Permalinks page.

**How do I add a custom post type slug to Settings > Permalinks page?**

Update:

In the end I created a form field in the plugin settings page and I updated the filter like this:

```
function register_post_type_args( $args, $post_type ) {

  if ($this->plugin_name === $post_type ) {
    $slug=get_option( $this->plugin_name.'_slug' );
          if($args['rewrite']['slug']!=$slug){
      $args['rewrite']['slug'] = $slug;
    }
  }
  return $args;
}
```

But I'm still looking for a way to change the slug from Settings / Permalinks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugins like this:

- Toolset Types
- Custom Post Type UI

Comment: I can't use a plugin. I need to build this for a client. It needs to be in the movies plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [WordPress Settings API](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/settings-api/):

1. Add a setting field for your slug, attached to the permalinks page with `add_settings_field()`
2. Write the callback function to display the `<input>` fied in the page
3. Write the function that record the value in the database after the form submission with `update_option()`

All you have to do then is modify your `register_post_type()` function. The `get_option()` function will return the value that has to be affected to `slug` (don't forget to test its existence).